# Dwarves not storing mugs in bins?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

[image: Top: Furniture Stockpile, Bottom: General Stockpile]

Top: Furniture Stockpile;
Bottom: General Stockpile;
My dwarves don't seem to be storing any of my mugs in my bins, the max bins i have designated is 35? I'm in version DF2014 v0.44.09

Comment: What version you on?

Comment: DF2014 v0.44.09

Comment: I think you should edit that in...

Comment: Mine those gems!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are out of free (empty) bins. Check your furniture stockpile or 'Stocks' from z-menu.
Each bin can store up to 5 bars or blocks, while 30 or more small crafts may fit into a single bin.

Or maybe your population are too busy. Like transporting large number of items from former stockpiles to another place.

Comment: The last time I checked, I had a dwarf or two designated to haul, but they had no task.

Comment: Also I do have free bins, I checked

Comment: Maybe it is just an issue with this fort? A lot of things I designate never happen when there are plenty of dwarves to do so. I think I'm just gonna flood the place and start anew.